# Creating VR Headset Video

Tags: software-engineering, graphics-programming, virtual-reality

So I have a video stream of known resolution and I have a VR headset via HDMI at a known resolution.

Is there an existing library to create the slight fisheye and side-by-side layout for these single screen headsets? (It's a custom build, so no hardware locked API please)

Target: Win 7/8/10

Comment: Which language would you want the library for?

Comment: I'm good for anything. I mostly use C/C++/C#, Python, QT

Comment: Note: the calculations for determining the amount of distortion (chromatic and barrel) required for an HMD is something like a 7th degree polynomial and dependent on your specific lenses. Rendering a screen-space quad and tweaking the distortion in a shader by tial-and-error is your best bet.

Answer (score -1):

It is not easy to go through the entire way. There are no current libraries combining those stuffs you want. But you can make a custom design basing on open libraries and graphic languages(Let us leave aside argument that opengl and d3d is not languages). Firstly, you should begin with a Video decode library like FFmpeg.
Then, assuming you good at one of opengl/gles/vulkan/d3d/mental or other graphic languages, you should build a scene for you video.  slight fisheye and side-by-side layout are just little trick in graphics, you should achieve if you good for graphics principle.I think it is enough for you goals. Tial-and-error is a good method as  XGundam05 says.
Good lucky.